# What is the easiest way to display information on the Jenkins UI from a groovy system script?

Tags: groovy, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am very reluctant to jump into having to write a full fledged plugin, and I only know of one way to inject some information onto the build status screen of a build: set the build description.

I would like to display and dynamically update a more complex piece of rendering onto the build status page from a groovy system script. What is the best way to achieve it? Do I have to write a full plugin and grok the whole stapler paradigm?

Comment: I guess what would be cool is to have a plugin which takes care of the mess and provides a simple `render()` function to render any html on the build status page - pretty much the way description works, without the side effect of also decorating the build list.

Comment: Christian, you can. Look at https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Summary+Display+Plugin and  it's sources https://github.com/jenkinsci/summary_report-plugin

Comment: What I need is a progress report, preferably updating live while the build is going on. Publishing results once done, there are plenty of plugins for that.

Comment: Bit what information do you want to publish?

Comment: I mean, statuses, build log, something else? In fact you can read build log, for instance. But it wouldn't be achievable from Groovy script, as it would be just a build step.

Comment: My immediate goal is to implement a status display similar to the one used by the multijob plugin. This is to build out an alternative job scheduler, which I asked about here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32704360/how-can-i-trigger-a-jenkins-job-upon-completion-of-a-set-of-other-jobs

Comment: I think you are looking for something like the 'Workflow Stage View Plugin' of the Enterprise Jenkins' version.

Comment: You can check this link too: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOmFXFq3Uzg

Comment: I guess if I shell out the big bucks for CloudBee's solution, I might get what I want... It's not that I am disinclined to shell out big bucks, it's the fact that it will take me about a year of using it to decide whether it was worth it...

Answer (score 2):

I had good experience with the following 2 plugins, both were used from within a pipeline:

1. The [Groovy Postbuild Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin) - just use `manager.createSummary` and add HTML to it. I found this to be easy to implement, with great UI results - it looks like built-in Jenkins sections. This is my personal recommendation.
2. As already suggested by stanjer, The [Summary Display Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Summary+Display+Plugin) also works. However, it is more cumbersome to use, as you need to generate a custom XML file with non-standard HTML tags in it, then add it as a build artifact and reference to it from the plugin.

Comment: These add entries after the build completes. What I'd like is something I can insert while the build is still in progress,

Comment: True about "Summary Display", but from what I've seen, the "Groovy Postbuild" does that during the build. You may also use a "parallel" block inside a pipeline, with one executor doing the actual job, while the other checks and updates the status.